# How do I update the state (using ReactJS) if I should not call setState in componentWillUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I `setState` in `componentWillUpdate`, `componentWillUpdate` runs in an infinite loop that doesn't stop getting triggered.

This never gives my `render` a chance to reflect my changes. How can I change the state if I shouldn't use `componentWillUpdate`?

Edit: I already have some understanding that `setState` should not be called in componentWillUpdate. I'm just confused what I should do as an alternative.

Edit #2: I started with `componentWillReceiveProps` but I can't seem to trigger this function when my Parent component changes state. I provide that state from the parent as a props to my child.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First thing to do is to check official documentation for this method ([link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate)). Where you can read when the function is actually called.

Then read common mistake(note):

> You cannot use this.setState() in this method. If you need to update state in response to a prop change, use componentWillReceiveProps instead.

You change the state and React automatically calls `componentWillUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks! I've read the docs but didn't grasp the idea of props and states triggering componentWillUpdate. Actually, I wanted to call componentWillUpdate because I am receiving new props from a Parent. However, I want to process the data in the props before I let my data render. Does that mean I don't need to call setState and just directly manipulate the props?

Comment: @David, do you change children props after mounting them to the dom? You should never directly manipulate props as it won't trigger a props changed event.

Comment: I have something like this:


`<div>
        <h1>This room is currently {this.props.roomId}</h1>
        <SongQueue queue={this.state.queue}/>
        <Search addSongToQueue={this.addSongToQueue}/>    
      </div>`

The `this.state.queue` is changing, but my child `SongQueue` can't seem to receive it properly.

This is in the `render` of my first main parent component.

Comment: If you won't be able to resolve this issue, you can post your problem as new question. Sorry, hard to understand in just comments.

Comment: Note that most times you can just use the props directly instead of setting it as an internal state. You can also inline modifications in the render method. This saves a lot of headache.

Comment: What about if you want to set state in response to a state change? E.g. one piece of state information can only be obtained by an asynchronous call based on some other piece of state information. In these cases I think (?) the React way is to split the component in two but I also feel it is valid to call `setState` inside `componentWillUpdate` with the caveats I describe in my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37448089/274677

Answer (score -1):

I understand this is cautioned against in the [guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate) but I am not sure I can see the problem with calling `setState` from within `componentWillUpdate`. True, it may result in infinite recursion **unless** of course you provide a bottom to that recursion (a way to break out of it). E.g. a way could be to check the second (`nextState`) parameter in `componentWillUpdate` and not invoke `setState` again if some condition is met (which is when the recursion ends).

As a minimal example, imagine a component that has no properties at all, only two  pieces of state. Further imagine that the second piece of state is asynchronously obtained from the first. E.g. the first piece of state could be some parameter to provide to an Ajax call, and the second piece of state is the result of that call. So basically you call `this.setState` to configure the parameters and then inside `componentWillUpdate` you can do something like the following (to keep things simple I use a `window.setTimeout` as a placeholder for an Ajax call):

```
const ComponentWithAsyncState = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            ajaxParams: '',
            ajaxResult: ''
        };
    },
    setAjaxParams: function(params) {
        this.setState({ajaxParams: params});
    },
    componentWillUpdate: function(_, nextState) {
        if (nextState.ajaxParams!=this.state.ajaxParams)
            window.setTimeout(function imagineThisIsAjax() {
                this.setState({ajaxResult: `result from ${nextState.ajaxParams}`});
            }.bind(this), 2000);
    },
```

When, (e.g. through some controls managed by this component) the `ajaxParams` change, the sequence of actions will be something like (where `~~>` denotes asynchronicity):

```
setAjaxParams --> this.setState --> componentWillUpdate ~~> imagineThisIsAjax --> this.setState --> componentWillUpdate
```

I.e. the second call to `componentWillUpdate` will not result in a further `this.setState` and thus the recursion will end there.

Comment: React components should really only be about displaying data given to it. Which is why they introduced Flux to handle the data flows, and react just displays it. Having this.setState() inside componentWillUpdate screams business logic in the view layer, which is the case in your example.
Of course you can just do whatever you want, and it *will work*. But I believe there are better tools (patterns) you can use to do it without a risk to an infinite loop.

Comment: to use setState on componentWillUpdate is not recommend because of call loops (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)

Comment: @the_bluescreen I am of course aware of that, which is why I speak of the possibility of infinite recursion and note that if you provide a bottom to the recursion you don't have this issue. Apparently you didn't read the answer or failed to understand it. Oh, and thanks for the link but it's already in my answer.