# Why do componentWillUpdate() and componentWillMount() not trigger render function when setState used in these methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, reactive-programming

We can call setState() inside every component lifecycle methods.

**Why do we not call it inside componentWillUpdate() and componentWillMount() ?**

**Why don't these methods trigger render function when put setState inside those ?**

Can anyone explain it in detail please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Some related discussion (some say "these methods should be concerned purely with rendering, no 'business logic' in there, please") at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945089/how-do-i-update-the-state-using-reactjs-if-i-should-not-call-setstate-in-compo?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**setState() in componentWillMount()**

> `componentWillMount()` is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before `render()`, therefore setting state in this method will
>   not trigger a re-rendering.

`setState()` in `componentWillMount()` will not trigger a **re-render**, but we have never called `render()` at this point yet. So, setting state here will prepare the state object before we enter the first `render()` pass.

Actually, for preparing state object for our very first `render()`, a better way is to use the `constructor()` instead of calling `setState` in `componentWillMount`.

More reading:

- [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)
- [a more comprehensive unofficial doc](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/premounting_with_componentwillmount.html)

---

**setState() in componentWillUpdate()**

> Note that you cannot call `this.setState()` here. If you need to update
>   state in response to a prop change, use `componentWillReceiveProps()`
>   instead.

`componentWillUpdate()` is called every time a re-render is required, such as when `this.setState()` is called. The reason we do not call `this.setState()` here is that the method triggers another `componentWillUpdate()`. If we trigger a state change in `componentWillUpdate()` we will end up in an infinite loop.

More reading:

- [Official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)
- [comprehensive unofficial doc](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/tapping_into_componentwillupdate.html)

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Sorry I have only 11 rep can't vote under 15 :) I am new.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking `setState()` will cause component to re-render. Once a component rerenders, it will call those methods. So calling `setState` inside those methods might trigger a rerender loop since it's unable to finish rendering the component.

Answer (score 0):

Component is re-rendered based on its state changes, and React determines when and what should be updated in next render. `setState()` might be asynchronous and React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.

You can't call `setState()` in these methods is simply because they're designed to do something before actual mounting/updating occurs. They're not for initiating a new render.

Facebook explains component lifecycle [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html).